# Get index of QPushButton on 2D array QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt

I have an 2D array `QPushButton`, how can I get index of the button when user clicks on its? such as When user clicks on the button `a[2][3]` it will show `(2,3)` ?

Comment: You'll need to expand on that slightly, how are you creating the buttons? How are you adding them? Where do you want to show that value?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The example looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

### Qt 4/5 Using Object Names

You can give your buttons unique object names. The names should ideally be valid C++ identifiers.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/button-grid-22641306
#include <QtGui>
#if QT_VERSION_MAJOR >= 5
#include <QtWidgets>
#endif

struct Display : QLabel {
   Q_SLOT void onClicked() {
      auto const elements = sender()->objectName().split('_');
      auto const i = elements.at(1).toInt();
      auto const j = elements.at(2).toInt();
      setText(QString{"(%1,%2)"}.arg(i).arg(j));
   }
   Q_OBJECT
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a{argc, argv};
   QWidget window;
   QGridLayout layout{&window};
   QVarLengthArray<QPushButton, 12> buttons(12);
   Display display;

   const int rows = 4, columns = 3;
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++ i)
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
         auto & button = buttons[i*columns+j];
         button.setText(QString{"(%1,%2)"}.arg(i).arg(j));
         button.setObjectName(QString{"buton_%1_%2"}.arg(i).arg(j));
         layout.addWidget(&button, i, j);
         display.connect(&button, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(onClicked()));
      }
   layout.addWidget(&display, rows, 0, 1, columns);

   window.show();
   return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

### Qt 5 - Using Lambdas

In Qt 5 and C++11, you should use functors to generate custom slot for each button, on the fly. For example:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/button-grid-22641306
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a{argc, argv};
   QWidget window;
   QGridLayout layout{&window};
   QVarLengthArray<QPushButton, 12> buttons(12);
   QLabel display;

   const int rows = 4, columns = 3;
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++ i)
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
         auto text = QStringLiteral("(%1,%2)").arg(i).arg(j);
         auto & button = buttons[i*columns+j];
         button.setText(text);
         layout.addWidget(&button, i, j);
         QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&display, text] {
            display.setText(text);
         });
      }
   layout.addWidget(&display, rows, 0, 1, columns);

   window.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

### Qt 4/5 - Using QSignalMapper

`QSignalMapper` is pretty much designed for what you want. It lets you map a `QObject*` to "something else", like a string. For example:

```
#include <QtGui>
#if QT_VERSION_MAJOR >= 5
#include <QtWidgets>
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a{argc, argv};
   QSignalMapper mapper;
   QWidget window;
   QGridLayout layout{&window};
   QVarLengthArray<QPushButton, 12> buttons(12);
   QLabel display;

   const int rows = 4, columns = 3;
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++ i)
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
         auto text = QString{"(%1,%2)"}.arg(i).arg(j);
         auto & button = buttons[i*columns+j];
         button.setText(text);
         layout.addWidget(&button, i, j);
         mapper.connect(&button, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(map()));
         mapper.setMapping(&button, text);
      }
   display.connect(&mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), SLOT(setText(QString)));
   layout.addWidget(&display, rows, 0, 1, columns);

   window.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

### Qt 4/5 - Using the Property System

You can leverage the fact that a `QWidget` is a `QObject`. QObjects have a property system, so you can set each button's index as a property, and then retrieve it in the slot connected to the `clicked()` signal. For example:

```
#include <QtGui>
#if QT_VERSION_MAJOR >= 5
#include <QtWidgets>
#endif

const char kIndex[] = "index";
struct Display : QLabel {
   Q_SLOT void onClicked() {
      setText(sender()->property(kIndex).toString());
   }
   Q_OBJECT
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a{argc, argv};
   QWidget window;
   QGridLayout layout{&window};
   QVarLengthArray<QPushButton, 12> buttons(12);
   Display display;

   const int rows = 4, columns = 3;
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++ i)
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
         auto index = QString{"(%1,%2)"}.arg(i).arg(j);
         auto & button = buttons[i*columns+j];
         button.setText(index);
         button.setProperty(kIndex, index);
         layout.addWidget(&button, i, j);
         display.connect(&button, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(onClicked()));
      }
   layout.addWidget(&display, rows, 0, 1, columns);

   window.show();
   return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Superb, I always like answers which show several ways to achieve same thing, and *“The whole is greater than the sum of its parts.”*

Answer (score 0):

in general, you would have to loop over the array and test the event target for equality with each element until you reach the correct index

Comment: In general, not. You can use the property system, or you can use the lambdas. Keeping the pointers to the buttons in a separate array is unnecessary.

Comment: Heck, you can use a `QSignalMapper`, too.

Comment: I meant, in general, that's what happens behind the scenes, and can lead to faster code if done manually in some cases, but your information, is most likely ore beneficial to the poster