# How to determine which widget triggered the slot function?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have an array of 10 objects, each having 8 parameters, all represented in GUI. I'd rather not have 80 slots defined; I'd much prefer to have 1 slot handling all the GUI triggered changes:

```
// Connect 10 Term objects
for( int n = 0; n < m_MaxTerms; ++n )
{
    // Connect several checkboxes for the nth Term item
    connect(m_Term[n].m_CD.GetData(), SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(UpdateTerm()));
    // Connect several edit fields for the nth Term item
    connect(m_Term[n].m_Volume.GetData(), SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this, SLOT(UpdateTerm()));
    ...
}
```

When UpdateTerm() is called I need to update the corresponding data based on the changes in the widget that triggered it. But how could I tell, from within UpdateTerm(), what widget triggered it? One way to solve the problem is to update data from **all** widgets when the slot is triggered by **any** of them. However, this is very inefficient; updating **only** the changed item would be much preferred.

Thus the question: is it possible from the slot function to determine which of the widgets triggered it? What would be the cleanest method of doing so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get index of QPushButton on 2D array QPushButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641306/get-index-of-qpushbutton-on-2d-array-qpushbutton)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `QObject::sender()` function to determine which object emitted the signal. This function is documented [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender).